# How to style the toggle effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am a newbie to html and CSS. I am designing a website for our [conference](http://iclaa2017.com).I am using the following code to get a toggle effect for the invited speakers of our conference which will give a drop down list box carrying their research interests.

```
<tr><tr><tr><td><th></th></td></tr></tr></tr><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.maindrop{
  width:50%;
}
.bar{
  padding: 20px;
color: white;
background: #1FB5AC;
display: block;
font-family: Times;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
}

.bar:hover{
background: gray;
}

.dropbox{
  height: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width : 100%;
   transition-property: background;
  transition-timing-function: linear;   
}

.dropbox:target{
  height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="maindrop">
  <div class="fold default">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab1">Speaker 1</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab1'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold" >
    <a class="bar" href="#tab2"> Speaker 2</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab2'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab3"> Speaker 3</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab3'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab4"> Speaker 4</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab4'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Quesitons:

First of all the animation is not working properly. The drop down box should come slowly and gently. ( I think I am missing some animation effect!!!)

What I am missing??

Second thing, for the first click drop down box visible, then in the second click one can make the box to reset know. How to do that?

PS: If there any styling option which will make the look better, kindly feel free to edit the code. I will be expecting a pleasant and elegant way of giving information about the speakers of the conference.

Comment: you have no `transition-duration` specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.maindrop {
    width: 50%;
}
.bar {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #1FB5AC;
    display: block;
    font-family: Times;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
}
.bar:hover {
    background: gray;
}
.dropbox {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropbox:target {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="maindrop">
        <div class="fold default">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab1">Speaker 1</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab1'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab2"> Speaker 2</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab2'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab3"> Speaker 3</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab3'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fold">
            <a class="bar" href="#tab4"> Speaker 4</a>
            <div class="dropbox" id='tab4'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> First of all the animation is not working properly.

The main issue you have is that the browser cannot animate between `height:0;` and `height:auto;` - the browser needs an explicit start point and an explicit end point to animate between.

So you could (for example) animate between `height:0;` and `height:200px;` - but the problem (self-evidently) with that is that not all the Speaker Profiles will be the same length and you don't want to have to manually input different heights for each new profile (including when each profile is edited).

So, the solution is to apply the `height` value through javascript instead of CSS. Then you can animate between:

```
dropbox.style.height = '0';
```

and

```
dropbox.style.height = dropbox.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

The second issue you have is that an open dropbox is not closing when clicked on for a second time. This is because you are using the `:target` pseudo-class to detect the first click... but then if you click for a second time on the same dropbox... the dropbox is still the focus of `:target` - so nothing changes.

Instead you can add and remove the class `.open` using javascript. The script will check to see if the fold is open - if it isn't, it will open it, if it isn't, it will close it.

**Working example** *(with Speaker Profiles of different lengths)*:

```js
var folds = document.getElementsByClassName('fold');

function toggle(fold) {

    var dropbox = fold.getElementsByClassName('dropbox')[0];

    if (fold.classList.contains('open')) {
        dropbox.style.height = '0';
    }

    else {
        dropbox.style.height = dropbox.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }

    fold.classList.toggle('open');
}


function speakersAccordion() {
 var openFolds = document.getElementsByClassName('open');

    for (var i = 0; i < openFolds.length; i++) {
    if (openFolds[i] === this) continue;
    toggle(openFolds[i]);
    }

    toggle(this);
}

for (var i = 0; i < folds.length; i++) {
folds[i].addEventListener('click',speakersAccordion, false);
}
```

```css
.maindrop{
width:50%;
}

.bar {
display: block;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Times, serif;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
background-color: #1FB5AC;
}

.bar:hover {
background-color: gray;
}

.dropbox {
height: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
width : 100%;  
}

.dropbox p:first-of-type {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindrop">
  <div class="fold default">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab1">Speaker 1</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab1'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold" >
    <a class="bar" href="#tab2"> Speaker 2</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab2'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab3"> Speaker 3</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab3'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fold">
    <a class="bar" href="#tab4"> Speaker 4</a>
    <div class="dropbox" id='tab4'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam diam enim, interdum eget iaculis in, pretium non libero. Pellentesque id interdum risus, vitae iaculis ipsum. Duis mi tortor, sodales nec nisl nec, venenatis sollicitudin turpis. Pellentesque hendrerit nec massa sit amet scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque a mi sit amet metus hendrerit placerat. Duis ullamcorper lectus vel erat luctus egestas. Maecenas pharetra justo sed nulla blandit, ut viverra diam posuere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```